# Webview not call any callback when run on app dual in android 11 (samsung device)

Tags: webview, android-11

i have a problem with webview when my app run as app dual in android 11 (samsung device).

When i load a url like:`mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com")`

I had to set a WebViewClient and override some method like: onPageStarted, onPageFinished, onReceicedError,... But there is no callback was called.

 **Note:** My main app work fine but its dual app is not and it only in android 11.

I had google but I dont have any information more.

I had try some thing like: restart device, update android system webview. But it don't affect

Happy to see any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the answer, the problem relative to [Package visibility filtering on Android](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility).

By the document **"When an app targets Android 11 (API level 30) or higher and queries for information about the other apps that are installed on a device, the system filters this information by default. The limited package visibility reduces the number of apps that appear to be installed on a device, from your app's perspective."**

So in this case package "**com.google.android.webview**" is not visible with my app when it try to load any url.

Conclusion, you just add this snipe code below in to your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.webview"/>
</queries>
```